# git diff standardized/normalized output

Tags: git, git-diff

We are working on a project where we run a script to generate patch files with `git diff` and/or `git show`. This patch file is then committed to git.

By default, `git diff` can have a different output depending on the local git configuration. This causes undesirable noise if a developer updates the patch file on their own machine.

Examples:

- Different length of the file blob hash. This can be fixed by `--full-index`.
- Path prefixes "a/" and "b/" are being swapped when running with `-R` parameter (reverse diff), and omitted if the local configuration has diff.noprefix = true.
- The "context" of each git snippet: E.g. sometimes I see a PHP class name there, sometimes a PHP function name, for the same diff in the same project on different environments.

Is there a recommended way to guarantee a standardized output format for git diff?

(I suppose the same would work for git show, but let's focus on git diff)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is just to stop git loading the user config in the first place. If there's an official way to do this I don't know it, but this trick will work:

```
env HOME=/nowhere git diff
```

Comment: This way you avoid using global user config but system config and repository config are still used.